# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.getAppContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "permission denied, please enable it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        if (!mydir.exists()) {
            mydir.mkdirs();
            if (!mydir.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "dir not made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        File file = new File(mydir, fname);
        String s = file.getPath().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); //error appears here
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(this);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
```

I get the following error, I have manually enabled the permission for the app:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/iCHMF/elasticDefault.dat (Is a directory)

fname is the file i want to output "/elasticDefault.dat"
problematic code line is here.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)
```

Comment: @Thomas may i know what do u mean by that? I enabled the app permission through the settings>app permissions. I want to know why my file was detected as a directory

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread is as "disabled". Did you check the file exists and _is_ a file? Did you make sure your app as write permissions for the directory and file?

Comment: @Thomas if i run this code mydir.mkdirs(); does it mean i should be able to see the folder created? cause i dont see it in my files. However, mydir.mkdirs(); returns true

Comment: Hmm, are you sure `if (!mydir.mkdirs())` returns true? You're calling `mydir.mkdirs();` right before that and if this call fails the following should fail as well while if the first succeeds the second should still return false because everything should already exist.

Comment: @Thomas not sure what happened but added the check for whether the file exist, it went through. The folder was found in my internal storage instead of my sd card